# $_FILES[..]['tmp_name'] doesn't exist

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to make a file upload form using PHP. `$_FILES['main_image']` prints as:

```
Array
(
 [name] => kitten11.jpg
 [type] => image/jpeg
 [tmp_name] => /tmp/phplyPTRW
 [error] => 0
 [size] => 29872
 )
```

`file_exists($_FILES['main_image']['tmp_name'])` is `false`, and `/tmp` is writable.

What could possibly be happening?

I'm on dumb shared hosting, so I can't change much as far as configuration goes.

**EDIT**

One of my includes did something it should't, so problem solved.

Comment: The file is automatically deleted after the script runs. Are you processing it on the same or a subsequent request?

Comment: Assuming then that it works in your own local environment, I would contact tech support and ask them. Probably they are being sent to a global /tmp folder while you are jailed inside a local /tmp folder. If it were a typical PHP problem, then `error` would likely be non-zero.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to edit **`php.ini`** file and increase the value of this line :

> **upload_max_filesize**

Answer (score -1):

In that case `file_exists()` may not be relevant. Many times a wrong **$destination** path for the `move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination)` function is the problem.

Please, could you check this value, whether you are using that upload function?